# Adjusted width of grid column in Vaadin?

Tags: java, eclipse, grid, vaadin

how can I tell a grid in Vaadin to adjust the width of its columns to the length of their entries? (In order to use as few space as necessary)

I develop the application for which I need the grid in Java (Eclipse), using the Vaadin plugin.

Thx for your help,

simon1440

Answer (score 1):

By default if you set grid to 100% width Vaadin will try to adjust width of its columns to the length of entries.
You have option to change it with setWidth and setExpandRatio methods.

Please check this link: [Configuring grid columns widths](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/10674/Configuring+Grid+column+widths)

As you can see:

```
grid.getColumn("name").setExpandRatio(1);
```

expand ratio is probably the best option for custom settings, but you can not be sure that it fits for all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Simon the fact you need to remind, is you have to tell the columns which you wanna resize, whats there currently largest entry, focused on the length. So you have to update this information eacht time you add or delete an entry.

The easy fact here is to use the following code fragment caused by the Layout structure:

`yourCatalogue.setColumnExpandRatio(columnIndex, ratio);`

But remind the fact that some Browser versions will fail the margings during reload.

=> https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/10102487/10190604

At least sry for my worse grammar. :)